# Accepting name autocompletion proposal jumps to next browser-tab

Tags: support, comment-replies, autocomplete

When I want to reply to a user in the comments, it is common to use put the @-symbol in front of their username in order to notify them: `@UserName`.

This is described in this post in detail: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

However, when I start typing the username, I get a proposal for the username over the commentbox:

```
[hamena314] --- the proposal over the commentbox

@ha --- what I am typing in the commentbox
```

BUT I cant accept the autocompletion proposal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or any other key-combination.

Instead I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> which accepts the proposal **but jumps into the next browser-tab**!

Is there a way around this for me? Because the autocompletion would simply not be useful for me this way. Changing the keyboard-shortcuts in Firefox would also not be useful, as I keep switching machines / devices in my company.

Comment: I use just TAB.  No Ctrl.

Comment: Oh man ... this works, seems like I forgot to try the simplest option. Thanks!

Comment: I am not a smart man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either click the name with the mouse or hit "tab", as mentioned by ryanyuyu.

> [image: GIFS FOR TEH WIN]